# union of constraints

Tags: optimization, constraint

How to solve problems like $\min_x f(x) \\ g(x) < 0 \ or \ h(x)<0$?

I think we can solve $\min_x f(x) \\ g(x) < 0 $ and $\min_x f(x) \\ h(x) < 0 $, then we compare the solutions from these problems. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: It depends.  What form do $f,g,h$ take?  Are they linear?  convex functions?  boolean formula?  What is the domain for $x$?  integers?  real numbers?  0 or 1?  I encourage you to [edit] your question to provide more context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems can be formulated as a [Generalized Disjunctive Programming](http://egon.cheme.cmu.edu/Papers/IMAGrossmannRuiz.pdf) as follows where each function you mentioned can be assumed as a disjunct of the whole set.

\begin{split}
\min\ Z = &\ f(x) \\
\text{s.t.} \\
&\ \bigvee_{i\in D_k} \left[
    \begin{gathered}
    Y_{ik} \\
    g(x) \leq 0 \\
    h(x) \leq 0 \\
    \end{gathered}
\right] \quad k \in K\\
&\ \Omega(Y) = True \\
&\ Y \in \{True, False\}^{p}\\
\end{split}

further you can solve the problem by introducing the axillary binary indicator variables, $Y_{ik}$ to transform each disjunct to whose linear or non-linear (in)equality constraints.

Answer (score 4):

You could introduce binary variable $y$ and a large enough constant $M$. You can then modify your constraints in the following linear way:

\begin{align}
\min_x f(x) \\ 
g(x) < M \cdot y \\
h(x) < M \cdot (1-y)\\
y  \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

If $y=0$, $g(x)$ must be $<0$ and if $y=1$, $h(x)$ must be $<0$.